# Is there way to extract all number which belongs (Asia,AP,EU) in python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

My dataset

[image]

Code I have tried:

```
df = df.loc[df['column name']=='here i want to pass list']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
searchfor = ['Asia', 'AP', 'EU']
df = df[df['Region'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. And I wish you lots of success in 2021.

Answer (score -1):

try using merge function

First create a temperory data frame containing The list you are searching for

```
tempdf = pd.DataFrame({"Region":['Asia','AP','EU']})
tempdf
```

and then apply merge function with right joint as argument

```
pd.merge(df,tempdf,how="right")
```

you will get your data frame

[image: click on the image for more clarification]

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is no need to ask for upvotes on this site: we build the community to be aware of up- and down-voting.